# Parallelization and assumptions

Tags: list-manipulation, simplifying-expressions, parallelization

I'm having a simple problem. Here is the code

```
Table[Simplify[DifficultFunction[i],assumptions], {i,DifficultSet[1, 2]}]
```

the correct and simplified answer is

[image]

while if I try to parallelize:

```
Table[Simplify[DifficultFunction[i],assumptions], {i,DifficultSet[1, 2]}]//Parallelize
```

what I get is

[image]

which is still correct but not simplified. I used `$Assumptions`, but even if i put them as the se second argument of `Simplify` nothing happen. In my case it would be crucial to let different kernel simplify different expressions since in some cases this is the operation that requires a lot of time. How can I do?

## EDIT

The strange point is that if I use

```
IntermediateResult= Table[DifficultFunction[i], {i,DifficultSet[1, 2]}]
```

and *then*

```
ParallelTable[Simplify[i,assumptions],{i,IntermediateResult}]
```

it works.
How is this possible?

Comment: A concrete example would make this problem much easier to work with.

Comment: It's hard to make concrete examples: my file contains very complicated functions, and if I try to do a MWE it boils down to a triviality. However the edit I did should be independent on what are the definitions of my functions.

Comment: I understand that creating a minimum working example can be difficult.  Nevertheless I think it will be hard to answer your question without one unless someone has already experienced and analyzed this problem.  I hope for you that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

There can be several causes.

`$Assumptions` is not active on parallel kernels unless you explicitly set it:

```
ParallelEvaluate[$Assumptions = ...]
```

You should explicitly use `DistributeDefinitions` on any defined symbols that appear in the expression that you assign to `$Assumptions`.  `ParallelEvaluate` does not auto-distribute before version 10.4 (like most other parallel functions do).

Also keep in mind that the result from `Simplify` (and many other symbolic functions) may depends on what was previously evaluated. `Simplify` uses a time limit for trying certain transformations.  Whether it reaches that limit depends on the speed of your computer as well as what symbolic results were *cached* previously.  The cache state is not shared between parallel kernels.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had the suspect that assumptions could not be shered among kernels, so I manully put assumptions in the second argument of `Simplify`. What astonishes me is what I write afer the EDIT. It seems that if I insert an intermediate step, it works perfectly but this doesn't make any sense. Does it? 
P.S. My version is 11.0 so I shouldn't have the other issue you mensioned

Comment: @MaPo As Mr Wizard said, without an MWE it's hard to say much ...